# Check if user has already tweeted

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm working on a script that eventually will show the user a 'prize' if they tweet from the site. At the moment it only console.log's the word tweeted.

This is what I am using for the event that checks the tweet has been sent:

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
    console.log('Tweeted');
});
```

Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZwHBf/89/

Tweet using this button, then refresh the page.

The problem I am having is that the user has to click the tweet button every time they visit the page. Is there a way to check whether the tweet has already been tweeted by them and then to auto display the 'prize' ?

Comment: As a workaround, you could use persistent storage (depending of cache browser) as localstorage or cookie for older browsers

Comment: Hey @Danienllxxox, did you a get a way to achieve this?